# How identifiers are stored in memory?

Tags: java, c

any value assigned to a variable (e.g. int i=5) is stored in memory in hexadecimal form at some address.
So will the variable name(i) associated with the value is converted to ASCII code in memory while storing?

Comment: Not sure whether you're asking about Java or C, but the answer is _no_ in both cases.

Comment: "*...in hexadecimal form...*" No. Values are stored in binary using bits. All data is stored using bits, which is just a physical implementation of binary. Hexadecimal is just a convenient number system for programmers.

Comment: [Your computer is actually doing this when you say `int i = 5;`](https://godbolt.org/g/VxKtUu). It's allocating a small chunk of memory and assigning the value of 5 to it. The name of that variable is completely lost when translating from human readable code (C, in this case) to machine readable code (x86_64, in this case). Some languages support [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)), though, so (depending on the language) certain amounts of information about a particular variable might be available at run time. But C doesn't support reflection.

Comment: Identifers *aren't* stored in memory. *Values* are stored in memory.

Comment: What?  Current CPU's only operate on binary instruction codes and binary data.  That's it.  That's all there is.

Comment: All the answers have some truth. Bottom line is that names are not stored unless they are needed. Locals and parameters are generally not needed.  To help in debugging, they might be stored, perhaps in a [different file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/pdb-use-program-database).

Comment: Oh, Java's identifiers are not ASCII so they would be stored using a Unicode encoding, maybe _modified_ UTF-8. (Generally, if you think something is ASCII and can't cite a specification, it's probably not ASCII.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak to Java.

In C, variable identifiers are (usually) not preserved in the generated machine code.  Instead, you'll (usually) see objects referred to via an offset from a register.

For example, on my system, given the source line

```
i = 5;
```

my compiler generates the machine code

```
movl $5, -4(%rbp)
```

`%rbp` is the *base pointer register* - it stores the base address of a *stack frame*, which includes space for function arguments (if any), local variables (if any), and the address of the next instruction following the function call.  On my system, local variables are stored "below" the value in the base pointer register (negative offset), while function arguments are stored "above" it (positive offset).  The identifier associated with the function argument or variable is not preserved at all.

Answer (score 2):

The identifiers names are not retained in the assembly file after the compilation. They are maintained during compilation in a data structure called [Symbol Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table) which associates each identifier with the information about its declaration and memory address allocation.

During compilation, the identifiers are assigned a memory address which are then accessed using offset from base pointer of the memory stack assigned to the process.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Java stores that stuff.

**Answer:**

The runtime knows what type everything is because almost everything is an object, and every object has a method called “getClass()”, which will return the type of object.

That means when an object is passed to a method in Java, the parameter type is known,and also the type of object is known too. That means it’s pretty easy to work out if it’s a valid type to pass.

int in Java isn’t an object, but the type information is still there in both int parameters in methods, and easy enough to check if they match up.

The example of a 4 byte string vs. 32 bit integer would be a valid enough point in C, but not in Java, where strings are abstracted away from being simply character arrays of a given length. Strings are objects in Java, and not just a plain allocation of memory like in C.

Comment: But Java doesn't store the name of the (local non-member) variable itself.

Comment: @Cornstalks Well it does, but not in the way you expect it. Class files *can* contain a LocalVariableTable (but not necessary for running, and may be omitted), which describes which which index (sort-of a memory address) has which variable name and type for which part of the method (because the index may be re-used for different local variables in one method) https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.13